# Identifying a MOV

Tags: identification, mov

I have a buddy with a St. Croix Lancaster corn stove with a control board in it that was taken out by a malfunctioning generator (the pellet stove was not even turned on, but like most semi-modern appliances it still has power going to it).

I am certain this device is a MOV 120 V AC; the line fuse was taken out by the transient as well, and my buddy had removed it already so I do not know the current involved; I cannot for the life of me find a schematic for this board.

I am attaching pictures.

Most of the markings on the device were obliterated when the MOV sacrificed itself.

The device is approximately 7.6 mm in diameter. The part number for the entire control board is 80P52632-R.

Can anyone offer advice on what this component is so I can get a replacement?

[image: MOV1]

[image: MOV2]

Comment: If the MOV failed that hard, I think it's a fairly good bet that there are more components on the board that are damaged.  Since this board presumably controls combustion in or adjacent to an occupied dwelling, I would replace the entire thing.

Comment: The MOV is just there for surge suppression, it doesn't actually have a role in the machine's operation.  Finding a blown MOV is like rolling up to the  main gate of your highly secure facility, and finding the gate guards all shot dead.  *Replacing the guards is probably not your only problem*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace it with a 120VAC MOV of similar diameter. It will be close enough.

Comment: If the MOV failed and blew open, it probably also blew a fuse or other protective device. I would suggest being careful about powering up the unit after replacing the MOV - perhaps using a Variac to slowly apply voltage while monitoring current.

Comment: That was exactly my first thought as well. I do appreciate a second opinion!